# Resource group with Azure AD Domain Service is not getting deleted

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azureportal

While trying to create Azure Virtual Desktop, I have created one resource group with Azure AD Domain Service to bind Active Directory with Virtual Network.
At the cleanup time, I tried to delete the resource group which contains the Azure AD Domain service.

I tried to delete the resource group from Portal as well as from Powershell. Using the following command -

`Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name AADS | Remove-AzureRmResourceGroup -Verbose -Force`

But I am receiving following error.

Cannot modify resource with id '/subscriptions//resourceGroups/AADS/providers/Microsoft.AAD/domainServices/' because the resource entity provisioning state is not terminal. Please wait for the provisioning state to become terminal and then retry the request.

I attempted delete operation multiple times with an interval of around 2-3 hours but still getting the same error.

Comment: On powershell, the error description is as - `Remove-AzureRmResourceGroup : Long running operation failed with status 'Conflict'.
At line:1 char:39
+ ... esourceGroup -Name AADS | Remove-AzureRmResourceGroup -Verbose -Force
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Remove-AzureRmResourceGroup], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.RemoveAzureResourceGroupCmdlet`

Comment: you probably need to contact support. try deleting the resource manually first and then the resource group

Comment: I tried to delete the resource manually, but getting an error as "The managed domain is in a failed state. Contact support with your Azure AD tenant ID and the domain name of the managed domain.
". Looks like we need to contact support.

Comment: Hi Praveen, As a workaround you may try to delete required resource group by routing to https://resources.azure.com/ -> subscriptions -> <Your Subscription> -> Select <Your Resource Group> -> Actions (POST, DELETE) -> Delete. Note that before you try to delete, you may have to change the mode to "Read/Write" from "Read only" mode. Or another workaround you may try is to create another ADDS resource in same resource group and then try deleting the resource group.

Comment: open a support ticket. This question is not good fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: Yes, this issue got fixed by the Microsoft support team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue belongs to troubleshooting and was fixed by the Microsoft support team.

You can raise a support ticket on azure portal by following this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request