# Can't create Azure Active Directory - Domain Service - Code: RequestConfig

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-domain-services

I was facing an issue when tried to create and deploy a new AAD DS instance.
I got the following error:

```
{
  "code": "DeploymentFailed",
  "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "RequestConflict",
      "message": "Cannot modify resource with id '/subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/ADDS-resource-group/providers/Microsoft.AAD/domainServices/whatever.onmicrosoft.com' because the resource entity provisioning state is not terminal. Please wait for the provisioning state to become terminal and then retry the request."
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to redo the process multiple times without any success. Does anyone know, what might be the root cause, and how to fix it?

I am wondering if my subscription plan is too basic for AAD-DS?

Answer (score 0):

With Same error multiple issue has reported and it belongs to troubleshooting and fix by MS support team.

Please raise support ticket on azure portal by following this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request

Reference 1 : [Resource group with Azure AD Domain Service is not getting deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57480111/resource-group-with-azure-ad-domain-service-is-not-getting-deleted)

Reference 2 : [Error while updating secure LDAPS in Azure AD DS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/167209/error-while-updating-secure-ldaps-in-azure-ad-ds.html)